# How to pass an array of routes from blade.php to a Vue component in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a controller that is passing routes to a blade.php file. In that blade.php file, I am using a Vue component and passing `:routes` to the Vue component as props. The issue is, the controller is returning a collection of multiple routes but when I pass `:routes` to my Vue component it is erroring unless I only pass one route at a time. In my component, I have routes to be accepted as an array in the `props`. How do I pass an array of routes from blade to vue?

blade.php file

```
  <user-exam
        :routes="{{ json_encode( route('user.exam-start', ['exam' => $exam[0]]))}}"
  ></user-exam>
```

As you can see in the code above I am using the `[0]` index to pass in one route, I do not want to have to do this.

userExam.vue file

```
<script>

export default {
  props: {
    routes: Array,
  },
}
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty useless when it comes to Laravel but it sounds like you want to map the `$exam` array to an array of routes (returned by that `route` function).

Try this

```html
<user-exam
  :routes="{{ json_encode( array_map(function($ex) {
    return route('user.exam-start', ['exam' => $ex]);
  }, $exam) ) }}"
></user-exam>
```

Comment: this is helpful, the issue is my 2nd param for the array_map() method is an object not an array so it does not work as expected.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. In your question above, you use `$exam[0]` which shows that `$exam` is clearly an array

Comment: It was an array within an eloquent collection

Comment: Nope, still doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my issue, I ended up looping in the blade file like this

```
@foreach($exam as $ex)
<user-exam
        :routes="{{ json_encode( route('user.exam-start', ['exam' => $ex]))}}"
  ></user-exam>
@endforeach
```

THis ends up creating multiple instances of the vue component but it is working as I wanted it to.

Sin the vue dev tools you have something like:

```
<Root>
    <userExam>
    <userExam>
</Root>
```